# Php independent code-block

Tags: javascript, php, css, overriding

I've developed a **Php website** and one part of this website is the so called "**Dashboard**" where users can have multiple widgets. Now a friend of mine came up with the idea to enable **users** to **upload there own widgets**.. For now I just use Php's include to load the current users widgets like so:

```
  while($record=mysql_fetch_object($result)){
        print('<li class="widget">');
        print('<input type="hidden" class="wid" value="' . $record->wid . '">');

        include("../" . $record->wpath);

        print('</li>'); 
    }
```

BUT

1. What if the user accidently uses Php variables that I've already used in my code?
2. What if the user overrides my Css styles in his custom widget?
3. And what if his widget uses the same Js variables then I do?

So I want to build some kind of independent code-block which doesn't affect any other part of the website.. any ideas?

Comment: I think an iframe might be the solution but is there a frame-free solution too?

Comment: Letting users execute arbitrary PHP is absolutely asking for disaster. I'd strongly recommend only allowing HTML + Javascript.

Either way, be extremely careful the code is very isolated, since something nasty could wipe / reveal your entire site easily.

Comment: I have a 4th question... What if the user *intentionally* uploads a PHP code that drops your database? Or steal your db *connection string*?

Comment: thats quite far of being a good idea...

Comment: Ok I see your point and thats what I thougt too.

But questions #2 and #3 still remain..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a class and create objects to create the independent code blocks.
2. Wrap the css styles up into a css class.
3. Use OOP in initiating your Javascript variables and Set null to JS objects after your page is done with them.

You need to give the users a separate box to copy and paste the css which you can wrap into your own css class. Alternatively, you can use javascript to set/override the important css styles.

Answer (score 0):

Your include is dangerous. You should define a working directory and check the result of realpath('../' . $record->wpath) against your working directory to prevent directory traversal.

```
const WORKING_DIR = '/var/www/my-page';

$pathForInclude = realpath('../' . $record->wpath);

if ($pathForInclude !== false && strpos($pathForInclude, WORKING_DIR) === 0) {
    include($pathForInclude);
}
```

Comment: for now the users are only able to add widgets I've registered in my database so I guess this should be safe..